# SOQL Injection Error in Checkmarx Scanner Report

Tags: dynamic-soql, apex, checkmarx, soql-injection

I have a query similar to this in one of our apps,

```
 List<Account> accountList = Database.query('SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accIds');
```

But Checkmarx always gives SOQL Injection Error in report even when we are using variable binding. I also tried eascaping every single element in accIds, but still checkmarx gives SOQL Injection error. Can someone help in resolving this issue?

Comment: As this is a false positive (assuming your SOQL follows the same pattern) all you can do is note that it is a false positive when you submit your app for security review. The Checkmarx scanner has its limitations. Trying to construct a pattern that satisfies the Checkmarx scanner is introducing complexity for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code should not result in a SOQL injection finding as the scanner knows about bound variables -- if it does, please forward your code to sourcescanner@salesforce.com and we will investigate the issue.