# SOQL injection issue on source scanner report

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, failing-tests, security-scanner

I am getting SOQL injection vulnerability on source scanner report. Please check one of the issue below. I tried string.escapeSingleQuotes() on query string. It is helping with removing this issue in source scanner report but test classes are failing with *no viable alternative at character '\'* error. So unable to create a managed package with string.escapeSingleQuote() on query string.

> Object: newdraggableelementlist in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 593: String recId,List<String> newDraggableElementList)`

> Object: newdraggableelementlist in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 729: if(newDraggableElementList.size()!=0){`

> Object: newdraggableelementlist in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 730: for(String es:newDraggableElementList){`

> Object: es in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 733: newApiList.add(es);`

> Object: newapilist in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 750: for(String field:newApiList){`

> Object: field in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 751: if(field.subStringBefore('.')=='Account'){`

> Object: field in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 752: accountApiList.add(field.subStringAfter('.'));`

> Object: accountapilist in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 768: String accQueryString = String.join((Iterable<String>)accountApiList,',');`

> Object: accquerystring in file: classes/EsignWithSelectedTemplate.cls

`L 779: acc = Database.query('SELECT '+accQueryString+' FROM Account WHERE id =\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(recId)+'\'');`

instead of just recId, if I set total query string in escapeSingleQuotes, source scanner is not reporting as a vulnerability. but test classes is failing as I mentioned above. How to fix this issue? Where do I need to use String.escapeSingleQuotes() if I have to use only that method. Please advice.

Comment: This is probably a false positive. See this question for more info https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55234/soql-injection-error-in-checkmarx-scanner-report

Comment: Putting entire query in escape single quotes is not right because that would invalidate the query if there are any single quotes.

Comment: Yes. I am not putting entire query in singleQuote anymore as I mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple bind variables in dynamic SOQL query strings. 
So it would work if you change the query as follows.

```
Database.query('SELECT '+accQueryString+' FROM Account WHERE id = :recId');
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me. "L 779: acc = Database.query('SELECT '+accQueryString+' FROM Account WHERE id =:recId'); //'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(recId)+'\'');" is it because of commented part of line?? If not, it didn't fixed the issue.

Comment: @AshSFcloud Well, the scanner ignores the commented lines.